# Symmetric Cipher HDL

Tags: c#, encryption, vhdl, fpga, intel-fpga

Suppose an okay C programmer wanted to write VHDL code of a given symmetric cipher from scratch..anyone have any ideas or tips on an not overly difficult one to write?
It's just for proof of concept for a final year project. I have got AES working successfully using an opencores core.

Basically, I have a week to write a VHDL implementation. I would be above average at C but not great at VHDL so not looking for something too difficult. Was reading about the EStream ciphers and that. If someone could point me in the right direction...thanks!

P.S. My concern is I'll tackle something too awkward for implementation in an FPGA, considering the limited time I working with!

Comment: Is VHDL a must for this implementation? If not then you can pick up Verilog much sooner than VHDL as you are already good at C (just need to think in parallel instead in sequential -- In hardware things happen as soon as signal appears, in Software you have control over sequence of execution). Apart from that if you are limited on time and if its FPGA implementation then see if that FPGA allows converting and loading C code directly on FPGA (most of them do)

Comment: Thanks reply, no it's going to be VHDL. I've wrote a good few 'basic' VHDL programs with success as an warmup. It's relatively okay, what you see is what you get. Yeah I've come across soft-core processors instantiated in FPGAs running #C.
My goal is to utilize the FPGAs speed, via VHDL. There's a lot of ciphers out there so still trying to chose a relatively okay one to do..

Comment: Be careful about expecting magic speed increases from FPGAs - how are you going to get data to and from it (at a rate comparable to how fast you can get data in and out of your processor).   If you can't do that, you've just moved the problem from being compute-bound to I/O-bound (which is a [standard definition of a supercomputer](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.sys.super/QudD4KmUz-s/NemYWOvi5zcJ) :)

Comment: Oh I'm aware of that Martin, thanks. It's just a proof of concept - I wanted to use FPGA, soft processor etc just for my own learning - not an area my uni is big into. On a big learning curve.. I'm so busy with other subjects at moment I haven't started writing HDL yet, must nail down a cipher tonight.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an implementation of the Digital Encryption Standard (DES) in 1996 in 2 1/2 days, prefaced on understanding this particular (and now dated) symmetrical encryption algorithm quite thoroughly, not to mention VHDL as well. I also use little C programs to generate parts of the VHDL code (like test vectors for the test bench, S Boxes).  DES was originally required to be implemented in hardware, was described in one IBM patent at the RTL level while documented in FIPS Pub 46 in a neutral fashion there are reference implementations.

My implementation, which can be used as a reference isn't directly synthesis eligible, it has RTL level I/O buffers that would need to be removed. It also uses configuration to specify S Boxes in four otherwise identical byte register pairs of R and L as a component.  I've uniquified them before to use with a VHDL analyzer/simulator that hadn't yet supported configuration.

The largest part of the distribution is a PDF document on DES's permutations, which with an 8 bit interface is a transposition of 8 wires for the Initial Permutation, Inverse Initial Permutation and Permuted Choice 1 (with the addition of a 9th wire.  Also the E permutation is terribly regular.  The only irregular permutations are Permuted Choice 2 and the P permutation.  And of course there's the S Boxes.

DES can be implemented in around 4,700 NAND gate equivalents in it's simplest implementation, and there are test vectors with expected results.

See [vhdl_des.tar.gz](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25980826/vhdl_des.tar.gz) and [des.test](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25980826/des.test) (the test vectors) on Dropbox.

There's also a javascript DES implementation floating around that's been disabled to prevent it from using arbitrary keys in an educational environment. Capturing the page you can actual undo the disable allowing it to use arbitrary keys. See [JavaScript DES Example](http://people.eku.edu/styere/Encrypt/JS-DES.html). The value here is in showing off internal values for each round.

[A copy of JS-DES.html with writable keys can be found at [JS-DES.html](http://dpades.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/simu_js/JS-DES.html) http://dpades.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/simu_js/JS-DES.html, the project home page (http://code.google.com/p/dpades/) says it's GPLv2.]

You can use the javascript implementation to find round values for troubleshooting your implementation.

If it's not quite sophisticated enough for you, try Triple DES.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive reply...blew me away :) . I've downloaded the code; in 2 & 1/2 days is something else! I'm going to play around with the code tonight and see what hits home in terms of understanding. 
Initially, my plan was for a simple stream cipher - an implementation that wouldn't require 'alot' of code but I'll definitely look into 3DES.

Answer (score 0):

HDLs require a different mindset to development than software. You aren't going to be off and running from scratch in a week. You could try cribbing off of the original Verilog AES implementation (also on Opencores). The process of translating that to VHDL will teach you some things but you also won't learn to properly leverage VHDL features that Verilog lacks.

Comment: Cool, but I'm looking for a less used cipher that wouldn't involve as much... I know I can download different ones off the net. Was looking at writing out my own one on perhaps a new and emerging cipher..